# Hierarchy Viewer "Inspect Screenshot" shows nothing

Tags: android, hierarchyviewer

My AVD screen is:

[image]

And, when I open the hirarchyviewer from Android/sdk/tools, and click "inspect element", it shows the status bar "Loading pixel perfect data"...

[image]

...and them this status bar go away and nothing happens. As if I has just opened again the hierarchyviewer.

I'm on Windows 10, by the way.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate, I would suggest you to check UIAutomationViewer which will be found in [SDK_HOME]/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer.bat

Pros:

1. Colorful interpretation of views and their heirarchy
2. Can inspect any app installed on your device/emulator
3. Dump the hierarchy as UIX files and later import them.

Cons:

1. Resource-id are available only if the device are >= OS 4.3
2. Custom Views are shown as generic view from which they are inherited.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the command line version of Hierarchy Viewer. It has been deprecated.
Have you tried using Android Device Monitor? [Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) is how to open Hierarchy viewer from there. The monitor also has other features that might help you with what you want.

Comment: This is another problem...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382738/androidstudio-cant-open-hierarchy-viewer-metadata-is-read-only